# Server responds to non-www but not to www. DNS problems?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cname-record

The www. version of the site is not being routed. non-www version is served correctly.

My registrar is with FastHosts, and I am wanting to move from 1and1 to DigitalOcean for web server with Rackspace for Email.

I have set up the following name servers in FastHosts control panel yesterday:

```
NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
```

My zone file to show setup inside DigitalOcean is as follows:

```
$TTL    1800
@       IN  SOA NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.   hostmaster.xxxxx.co.uk. (
            1411945141 ; last update: 2014-09-28 22:59:01 UTC
            3600 ; refresh
            900 ; retry
            1209600 ; expire
            1800 ; ttl
            )
             IN      NS      NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
                     NS      NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
                     NS      NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
            MX 0        mx1.emailsrvr.com.
            MX 10   mx2.emailsrvr.com.
@   IN A    178.62.xx.xxx
www CNAME   @
```

dig command with www:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -t NS www.xxxxx.co.uk @ns1.digitalocean.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 146
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.xxxxx.co.uk.       IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxxxx.co.uk.    1800    IN  SOA NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM. hostmaster.xxxxx.co.uk. 1411908865 3600 900 1209600 1800

;; Query time: 171 msec
;; SERVER: 173.245.xx.xx#53(xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 29 00:12:07 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

dig command without www

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -t NS xxxxx.co.uk @ns1.digitalocean.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4963
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxxxx.co.uk.       IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxxxx.co.uk.    1800    IN  NS  NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
xxxxx.co.uk.    1800    IN  NS  NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
xxxxx.co.uk.    1800    IN  NS  NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.

;; Query time: 171 msec
;; SERVER: 173.245xx.xx#53(173.245.xx.xx)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 29 00:19:09 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual domain name?

Comment: Looks like its working just fine.  Can you be more specific as to what is NOT working? when you try to access the www. version, what happens?

Comment: That's weird... I've attached error msg too.

Comment: When I visit the www version, I get http redirected to the non-www version. I assume that is what you configured your webserver to do?

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted it to do... I don't get why I can only see non-www version. Because it means that the nameservers have propagated, but I thought I did something wrong with cname???

Comment: Based on the error screenshot, it looks like Virgin Media is your ISP? One it could just be that they their (Virgin Media's) resolvers havent updated yet and are basically NXDOMAIN hijacking..

Comment: What dig command are you actually running? It looks like you're looking up NS records, which would explain why you get results for the non-www entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS and your webserver are both absolutely fine!

Please clear your browser's cache, flush your dns resolver cache, and try again.

Comment: It's working now. Must have been Virginmedia's resolvers. Thanks for your help.